# How to update tkinter label with integer

Tags: python, tkinter, integer, label

I'm trying to have it so that when I press a button, the value of this label goes up, it's a score keeper. The error I get when I run my code is TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Label' and 'int' How can I fix this? thanks!
Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title('Basketball Score')
root.geometry("260x600")
point1 = Label(root, text=0)
point2 = Label(root, text=0)
def addone1():
    point1 = Label(root, text="0")
    point1 = point1 + 1
def addone2():
    point2 = Label(root, text="0")
    point2 = point2 + 1

titlelabel = Label(root, text="Basketball Score Keeper")
titlelabel.grid(row=0, column=3)

button1 = Button(root, text="Add Point", command=addone1)
button1.grid(row=1, column=0)
button2 = Button(root, text="Add Point", command=addone2)
button2.grid(row=1, column=5)

point1.grid(row=2, column=0)

point2.grid(row=2, column=5)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `point1 = point1 + 1` is incorrect as you are using the label itself and adding it to a digit, sort of like adding coconuts and oranges. You want to `point1.config(text=int(point1['text'])+1)`. Though a better approach is creating a label outside and then updating it constantly.

Comment: @CoolCloud `point1['text']`? I have a feeling OP may ask about `point` not being defined

Comment: Now, whenever I click nothing happens. The program runs without any errors but nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Kai Replace your function with the code I just gave.

Comment: @Kai well actually you are doing absolutely nothing in the current code example, those functions don't really do anything except waste resources

Comment: @Matiiss I changed point to point 1 and point 2

Comment: @CoolCloud I did, and nothing happens when I click

Comment: @Matiiss What do you mean, why is it not defined? `point1` is defined on global scope.

Comment: @Kai Works just fine for me.

Comment: @CoolCloud you had a typo: `point['text']` or so at least it seemed to me, also yes your answer works for you and probably everyone else if they know how to correctly implement it, maybe write an answer?

Comment: @CoolCloud I put my code in a pastebin bc it's too long for a comment: https://pastebin.com/ber0Qn3t

Comment: @Kai remove these parts from both functions: `point1 = Label(root, text=0)`

Comment: Thanks it worked! I really appreciate the help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding a `Label` with `int` and hence it gives error. Instead you should add the "text of the label" with the `int`. Just change your function to this:

```
def addone1():
    text = int(point1['text'])
    point1.config(text=text+1)
```

Or change your button `command` to this one-liner:

```
button1 = Button(...,command=lambda: point1.config(text=int(point1['text'])+1))
```

Though keep in mind, PEP8 isn't very fond of these one-liners...